# L'origine et la raison (historico-linguistique) de l'emploi de la préposition « de » dans la locution « d'accord » ?

Tags: prépositions, locutions, origine-ou-raison, linguistique, ancien-français

Pourquoi la locution adverbiale/prépositive *d'accord* est-elle formulée avec la préposition *de* plutôt qu'avec la préposition *en* (*je suis en accord* est cohérent). On note que la préposition *en* ne peut être employé là où on a simplement l'élision obligatoire (*il n'y a pas en accord du participe...* est incohérent ; *il n'y a pas d'accord du participe*). On a pris connaissance ailleurs ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11255/is-daccord-a-contraction), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/pourquoi-le-pronom-le-est-il-utilis%C3%A9-dans-mais-sa-m%C3%A8re-lest)) de l'idée d'unité lexicale par opposition à la simple élision ou à la contraction, voire la réduction de *d'un commun accord*, mais pourquoi cette « unité » se serait-elle constituée de cette manière...

---

Le dictionnaire [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/accord) note deux syntagmes attestés peu après 1160, à l'époque d'un français un peu différent, mais attesté ne signifie pas commençant là. Quoiqu'il en soit on a tout d'abord *d'un acort* (*et d'une volonté*), puis *d'accord*, attestés tous les deux dans le *Roman de Rou* (Wace) et on présente la [transcription](https://archive.org/details/maistrewacesroma01wace/page/48) de Andresen (*si bien d'acort*) alors que Pluquet [transcrit](https://archive.org/details/leromanderouetde01wace/page/50) plutôt « si bien acort ». On peut tenter de vérifier ce qui en est dans [Ms. Royal 4 C XI](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b10510319x/f449.item.r) partie 3, Fr. 375 ([directement ici](http://www.bl.uk/catalogues/illuminatedmanuscripts/record.asp?MSID=7658&CollID=16&NStart=40311)) ainsi que dans Fr. 718 et Duchesne 79. Bonne chance et de toutes façons ce n'est pas déterminant... L'expression elliptique *d'accord* (17<sup>e</sup>) provient de *être en accord* ou *mettre/être d'accord* [attestés](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k505878/f7.image) en 1538 (DHLF+TLF). On n'est pas vraiment plus avancé puisqu'on se base là encore sur *d'accord*, pas plus qu'on ne l'est à première vue en lisant sur l'histoire de l'élision en [versification](https://books.openedition.org/pup/1183?lang=en).

---

- Comment se fait-il que l'on ait être *d'accord* plutôt
  que *en accord* avec la locution<sup>1</sup> ; la comparaison avec
  *d'[abord](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abord)* est-elle d'une quelconque utilité (voir remarque après **II.** : ici *d'accord* n'a pas la fonction d'un *classificateur* et la sémantique de l'accord n'est pas diminuée comme l'est celle de l'*abord*) ?

  - Le cas échéant la préposition *de* est-elle néanmoins un sorte de
    « cheville » et pourquoi *en* ne l'aurait pas été ?

    - Si c'est le cas, peut-on expliquer la fonction (linguistique) autre que classificatrice de la locution et identifier l'origine de l'emploi de *de* comme « cheville » dans un tel contexte ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Différemment de l'[anglais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29238/what-is-the-meaning-of-d-in-daccord#comment59545_29238) incidemment, *in agreement* (ou avec le présent de l'indicatif, *I agree*), et où c'est de surcroît le participe/passé qui joue le rôle de la forme elliptique du français en interjection (*d'accord !*): *agreed!*.</sub>

Comment: Italien: *d'accordo*, espagnol: *de acuerdo*, catalan/occitan: *d'acord/d'acòrd*, portugais: *de acordo*, roumain: *de acord*.

Comment: On dit « je suis du même avis », qui a un sens proche, ou « je suis d'avis que etc. ». On dit aussi « je suis de cette sorte » pour indiquer une appartenance à une qualité particulière (« je suis de cette veine », « je ne suis pas né de la dernière pluie »). Je pense que le « de » fait référence à un état fini individuel, alors que « en » (« en accord », « en voiture ») fait référence à une partie supplémentaire.

Comment: Il est possible que la locution originelle était " faire quelque chose d'accord avec quelqu'un" et que la locution " être d'accord" est  une expression fautive qui est entrée dans l'usage. Il me semble que le " de" exprime un rapport de causalité comme dans " de gré ou de force". Si c'est le cas " être d'accord" n'a pas réellement de sens ( même si on le dit fréquemment aujourd'hui). En toute rigueur il faudrait dire " être en accord avec quelqu'un".

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames N'hésite pas à verser ça en réponse. Répondre fait boule de neige etc.

Answer (score 1):

Le *Grand Robert historique* indique (art. « accorder ») : Le déverbal *accord* possède deux valeurs dominantes. La première est liée au premier sens du verbe,  « pacte » et « conformité de sentiments, d'opinions » [...] d'où *être en accord* et *être, mettre d’accord* (1538), qui a donné naissance à l'expression elliptique très usuelle *d’accord* (XVIIe s.).  »

Pas d'autre explication, mais cela m’évoque une hypothèse.

Ne serait-ce pas que l'usage d'un verbe d'action (mettre) dans la forme *mettre d'accord* a concurrencé la forme avec verbe d'état (être) dans la forme *être en accord* ? L'action d'accorder impliquant une norme à laquelle calquer deux choses (comme, argotiquement, on *met d'équerre* – ou *de niveau*) plutôt qu'une harmonie dans laquelle ces choses se trouvent déjà, comme dans la forme avec verbe d'état (où sens où l'on est *dans* un état).

Comment: *Mettre d’équerre, mettre de niveau* sont d’origine artisanale, et concernent bâtiment ; ces usages ont servi ensuite à la comparaison d'idées ou de concepts de toutes sortes, l’argot le récupérant avec ses dérives habituelles n’apporte pas un éclairage nouveau. — « *Quand tout le monde* [instruments et musiciens]* est d’accord* », l’orchestre attaque sa première mesure … et le résultat est *d’un bon niveau* ;-)